# Por que el overlay y spinner deben ir al inicio del body?

Tags: html, css

Hola buenas soy nuevo en esto, querria saber porque el overlay junto con el spinner etc van al inicio del body, se que esta es la manera correcta pero alguna vez lo he puedo abajo y no hay problema, pero porque se suele poner arriba? 
Un saludo, gracias

```js
  $(window).on('load', function(){

    $('.overlay, .spinner').fadeOut(800, function(){

      $('h1').fadeIn(100).css('transform', 'scale(1.4)');

    });
  });



//             <-----OCULTAR NAVEGACION----->
$(window).on('scroll', parallax);

let ultimoScroll = 0;

function parallax(){

  let scrollActual = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scrollActual > ultimoScroll) {

    $('nav').addClass('oculto');

  } else {

    $('nav').removeClass('oculto');

  }
  ultimoScroll = scrollActual;
}


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', function(){

    let dataId   = $(this).data('id');
    let scroll   = $(window).scrollTop();
    let objetivo = $('#nosotros').offset().top;

    $('html').animate({
      scrollTop: objetivo
    },1000)

  });
});
```

```css
/* ------------------ ESTILOS GENERALES ------------------*/
body {
  overflow-x: hidden !important;      /* no es necesario */
  overflow-y: scroll;                 /* no es necesario */
  font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
  font-size: .95em;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #8d8d8d;
  background-color: #fff;
}

li{
  list-style: none;
}

p {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 2em;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1.313em;
  letter-spacing: 22px;
  font-family: 'Lato',sans-serif;
  color: black;
  margin-top: 240px;
  letter-spacing: 50px;
}


.spinner {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 47%;
  animation: girar .4s linear 100;
}

@keyframes girar {
  0%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25%{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  50%{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  75%{
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }

}

.overlay{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background:#BDBDBD;
  line-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  /*display: none;*/
}

h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.53846em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

h3 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.44444em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

h5 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.44444em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.mano-alzada {
  text-transform: none !important;
  font-family: "Georgia",sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.boton {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.boton.oscuro {
  border: 1px solid #555;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #111;
}

.boton.claro {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: #3f3f3f;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

.boton.naranja {
  border: 1px solid #bd9f86;
  color: #000;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}


.padding-section {
  padding-top: 120px;
  padding-bottom: 120px;
}

.grey-section {
  background-color: rgb(245,245,245);
}

.devider {
  width: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #bd9f86;
}

.subtitle {
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  font-family: "Georgia",sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #333;
}

.subtitle i {
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}



.border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.divisor {
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 10% auto 0;
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
}

.tachado {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}





/* ------------------ BARRA NAVEGACIÓN ------------------*/

nav {
  height: 72px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FAFAFA;
  padding: 1px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
  border-top: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
  z-index: 900;
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.190, 0.585, 0.285, 0.865);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
  color: #555;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 62px;
  margin: 5px 8px;
}

nav img {
  width: 60px;
  margin: 5px 10px;
  opacity: .8;
}




/* ------------------ SECCIÓN HERO ------------------*/

#hero {
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0) url("../img/backgrounds/bg-header.jpg") no-repeat fixed center bottom / cover;
}

#hero p {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Lato",sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#hero-noindex{
  padding:150px 0 230px;
}

#hero-noindex h1{
  font-size:4em;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#hero-noindex ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#hero-noindex ul li a{
  color: grey;
}

#hero-noindex ul li::after{
  content: " / ";
  margin: 0 10px;
}

#hero-noindex ul li:last-of-type::after{
  content: "";
}





/* ------------------ INTRO NOSOTROS ------------------*/


#intro-nosotros {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}


#intro-nosotros p{
  text-align: justify;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

#intro-nosotros h2{
  font-family: "Georgia",sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  color: black;
}

#intro-nosotros .videoContainer{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}

#intro-nosotros .videoControls {
  float: right;
}

#intro-nosotros .videoControls i::before {
  font-size: 21px;
}

#intro-nosotros #iconoPlayVid{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 9em;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index:500;
}

#intro-nosotros video{
  width: 100%;
}


#intro-nosotros .reveal {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(200px);
}


#intro-nosotros .reveal.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0px);
}




/* ------------------ SECCIÓN PROCESS ------------------*/

#process .facts {
  margin: 150px 0;
}

#process .numero {
  font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
  font-size: 14em;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #edefeb;
}


.facts article {
  padding-left: 60px;
}




/* ------------------ SECCIÓN SKILLS ------------------*/

#skills {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0) url("../img/backgrounds/bg-skills.jpg") no-repeat fixed center top / cover;
}

#skills .elemento {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Lato",sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#skills .marco {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}


#skills .elemento h5 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-family: "Georgia",sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #fff;
}

#skills i {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 4em;
  color: #fff;
}

#skills .numero {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
}



/* ------------------ SECCIÓN ABOUT ------------------*/

#about img {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#about .claimCruz {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 60px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0) url("../img/graphic/contain-cross.png") no-repeat center / contain;
}

#about article {
  margin-top: 17px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 27px;
}

#about .boton {
  margin-top: 40px;
}



/* ------------------ SECCIÓN VIDEO ------------------*/

#video {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0) url("../img/backgrounds/bg-video.jpg") no-repeat fixed center top / cover;
}


#video .roller{
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: url("../img/backgrounds/looping-blanco.png") no-repeat bottom right / contain;
}


#video h2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #fff;
}



#video i {
  font-size: 7em;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}



/* ------------------ SECCIÓN PROYECTOS ------------------*/

#proyectos {
  text-align: center;
  background: rgb(245,245,245) url('../img/backgrounds/looping-blanco.png') no-repeat scroll right bottom / cover;
}

#proyectos i {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #bd9f86;
}

#proyectos .boton {
  margin-top: 60px;
}



/* ------------------ SECCIÓN SERVICIOS ------------------*/

#servicios article i {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #bd9f86;
}

#servicios img {
  display: block;
  margin: 70px auto 40px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}






/* ------------------ HERO NOSOTROS ------------------*/

header.nosotros{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0) url("../img/backgrounds/bg-nosotros.jpg") no-repeat fixed center top / cover;
}




/* ------------------ EQUIPO NOSOTROS ------------------*/

#team{
  position: relative;
}

#team article{
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#team article.visible {

  transform: translateY(0px);
  opacity: 1;
}


#team article img{
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#team article ul{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 2em;
  background-color: white;
}

#team article ul .devider{
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 25%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bd9f86;
  opacity: .5;
}

#team article ul li a{
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  color: #bd9f86;
  font-size: .8em;
}

#team article header .devider{
  width: 50px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  opacity: .2;
}

#team .row:last-of-type{
  margin-top: 100px;
}

#team .claimbar {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../img/graphic/contain-line.png") no-repeat scroll center center / contain ;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

#team div[class^="progress"] {
  height: 4px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#team div[class^="progress"]:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background:black;
  height: 100%;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  transition: width .8s;
}

#team .progress70:before{
  width:70%;
}

#team .progress100:before{
  width:100%;
}

#team .progress90:before{
  width:90%;
}

#team .progress50:before{
  width:50%;
}

#team > img{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: .04;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* ------------------ SECCIÓN TRABAJOS ------------------*/

#trabajos {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0
}


#trabajos img {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(80%);
  filter: grayscale(80%);
}

#trabajos .container-fluid,
#trabajos .row,
#trabajos div[class^="col-"] {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* ------------------ EQUIPO TARIFAS ------------------*/

#rates article{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 30px 0 40px;
}

#rates .transparent {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #bd9f86;
}

#rates article header span{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

#rates article header h5{
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #555;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

#rates article .devider{
  width: 60%;
  margin: 20px 20%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

#rates article strong{
  margin: 40px 0;
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #555;
}

#rates article strong sup{
  font-size: .5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 2px;
}

#rates article ul{
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#rates article ul .cross p{
  text-decoration: line-through;
  opacity: .5;
}

#rates article:not(.transparent) .boton{
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}


/* ------------------ SECCIÓN CONTACTO ------------------*/

#contacto {
  background: rgb(50,50,50) none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

#contacto * {
  color: white;
}

#contacto .form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #000;
}

#contacto input:not(.boton),
#contacto textarea {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 5px 20px 20px 14px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Lato",sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1em;
  color: #fff;
}

#contacto .boton {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 40px;
}



/* ------------------ SECCIÓN FOOTER ------------------*/

footer {
  text-align: center;
  background: url("../img/backgrounds/bg-atracciones.png") no-repeat center bottom / cover;
}

footer h4 {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

footer a {
  color: #000;
}

footer .instagram li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

footer .sociales li {
  float: left;
}

footer address li{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/* ------------------ MODAL ------------------*/

.modalVideo {
  z-index: 8000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

.modalVideo video {
  display: block;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.modalVideo h3 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5em;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.modalVideo .fa {
  color: white;
  font-size: 5em;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 20px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer
}

#alerta {
  background: #FAFAFA;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .5s;
  color: rgb(50,50,50);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

#alerta.visible{
  transform: translateX(0);
}

#alerta p {
  padding: 12px 10px;
  border: 2px dashed rgb(50,50,50);
  margin: 10px 35px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 16px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <title>Central de ingredientes S.L</title>

  <!-- Descripcion en google -->
  <meta name="description" content="Desde 1994 somos tu proveedor de productos lácteos tanto nacional como internacional">

  <!-- Codificación -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <!-- Estilos -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font/flaticon.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

  <!-- Responsive -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

  <!-- Robots -->
  <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">

  <!-- Favicones -->
  <link type="image/png" rel="icon" href="img/favicons/cow-512-231943.png">


</head>
<body>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="containerOverlay">
      <div class="spinner"></div>
      <p>Cargando...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <header id="hero">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <h1>Central de ingredientes</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <img src="img/cow_Logo.png" alt="Logo">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu" data-id="inicio">Inicio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu" data-id="nosotros">Quienes somos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu" data-id="productos">Productos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu" data-id="calidad">Calidad</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu" data-id="logística">Logistica</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu" data-id="medio_ambiente">Medio ambiente</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="menu" data-id="contacto">Contacto</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <section id="nosotros" class="padding-extra">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xl-12">
            <h2>Somos [central de ingredientes] desde 1994</h2>
            <hr>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>Después de más de 20 años dedicado al sector lácteo, <span>central de ingredientes</span> se ha consolidado en el mercado, destacando tanto por su calidad, seriedad y confiabilidad en la fabricación tanto de preparados lácteos en polvo para chocolatería, como heladería o galletería. Incorporándose posteriormente al grupo su filial <span>Global blends ibérica</span></p>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="img/wallpapers/grey.jpg" alt="Photo">
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Realmente tu código funcionará igualmente aunque pusieras la función al final del script. Yo diría que no es tanto el orden si no elegir la función adecuada en cada caso. También, por temas de lectura, creo que lo mejor es ponerlas en orden de ejecución (onload, onready, etc...). Sin embargo, desconozco si hay algún estándar definido para ello.

Comment: jaja gracias por tu respuesta pero me referia al html, el div overlay con los demas para hacer el spinner... porque va al inicio del body?

Comment: Ahh, eso es para que no haya ningún elemento que "entorpezca" el poder posicionarlo libremente en la pantalla.

Comment: se puede poner en donde sea porque el spinner tiene un **position: absolute;**

Comment: @ReneLimon En caso de que no haya un elemento con **position: relative;** que lo englobe.

Answer (score 0):

Lo cierto es que **no hay ningún criterio de fuerza para colocarlo siempre** al principio del body y **de hecho pueden ir donde quieras**

> pero porque se suele poner arriba?

La razón es simple. **Porque muchos usuarios no conocen en principio como funcionan las capas de superposición de css, me refiero al `z-index`**, si revisas esta comunidad, verás que es una muy común y de fácil respuesta, pero en principio no es facil de comprender, por lo que por experiencia muchos desarrolladores que esta ayudando con tutoriales básicos, tienen estas prácticas con los más novatos, para no desviar el verdadero objetivo del tutorial al estar respondiendo sobre cómo funciona el apilamiento de capas.

Éxitos!